# Narrow down typescript type

Tags: typescript

I have a type like this:

```
type MyType = "One" | "Two" | "Three" | "Four" | "Five"
```

Now, in some cases, not all of the values of **MyType** are valid. So I want to have a type, which can have the same values as **MyType**, except a few of them. like this:

```
type OtherType = "One" | "Two" | "Five"
```

Basically, I want the second type to be a limited version of the first type. I'm not sure if this is possible; That's why I'm asking for help to make sure :)

I know I probably should make two different types BTW, but if this would be possible, it would save me from a lot of pain!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) for this:

```
type OtherType = Exclude<MyType, "Three" | "Four">;
```